# How to control audio/video original controls without creating custom controls

Tags: html5-video, html5-audio

I would like to control (play, pause, download, toggle full-screen, progress bar) the original controls of html5 `<video></video>` without making the customize button. I don't want to make custom controls. Or, is it the best answer to create custom controls by own?

The reason is I want to toggle when another video is playing or paused. The video player is paused when it is in the invisible area.

[I would like to control in javaScript when click original play/pause button like image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1mQa.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Give your `<video>` tag an ID then use Javascript functions to control it. See example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_play.asp

Comment: @VC.One When we give id and control in JavaScript function, we need to add custom button to toggle play/pause. Actually, I would like to control using original controls. Can I do that? thanks.

Comment: @MyatHsuMon The W3Schools link is just an example where **their condition** is _"If Pause button is pressed then do Pause function"_ ... In your situation, you don't create custom buttons to pause video, instead **your condition** is to do _"The video player is paused when it is in the invisible area."_ and whenever that part happens you then also run your own PauseVideo function code.